# How to write a query in SQLAlchemy with a self-referencing table?

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy, self-referencing-table

I have a self referencing table, that looks like this:

```
class Domain(Base):
    __tablename__ = "domains"
    domain_id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer(), ForeignKey('domains.domain_id'))
    domain_name = Column(String(255), unique=True)
```

Example of data:

domain_id,parent_id,domain_name

```
1,,google.com
2,,yahoo.com
3,1,images.google.com
4,1,drive.google.com
5,2,mail.yahoo.com
```

I need to write a query where all domains will be placed right after it's parent domain.

```
1,,google.com
3,1,images.google.com
4,1,drive.google.com
2,,yahoo.com
5,2,mail.yahoo.com
```

My best try is:

```
subdomain = aliased(Domain, name='subdomain')

domains = session.query(Domain, subdomain.domain_name)
domains = domains.outerjoin(subdomain, Domain.parent_id==subdomain.domain_id).filter_by(domain_name=None)

subdomains = session.query(Domain, subdomain.domain_name)
subdomains = subdomains.join(subdomain, Domain.domain_id==subdomain.parent_id)

query = domains.union(subdomains)
```

But the result is not quite the result I'm looking for.

```
1,,google.com
1,3,images.google.com
1,4,drive.google.com
2,,yahoo.com
2,5,mail.yahoo.com
```

domain_id and parent_id are reversed.